# Show/Hide div on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup, slidedown

I've got 4 divs and on click of the navigation I want to show one of them and hide the others. I have it working but I feel its not as smooth as I know it could be, its definitely my code that needs to be refactored! Heres what I have.

```
$('#details-speakers').click(function() {

    $('#home').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#sessions-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#cases-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#speakers-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
        $('#details-speakers').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-sessions').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-cases').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});
$('#details-sessions').click(function() {

    $('#home').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#speakers-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#cases-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#sessions-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('#details-sessions').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-speakers').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-cases').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});
$('#details-cases').click(function() {

    $('#home').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#speakers-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('#sessions-content').slideUp('slow', function() {});
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#cases-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('#details-cases').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-speakers').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-sessions').removeClass('selected');
        $('#details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smoothness or lackthereof is not the fault of your code. Some browsers are slow. It's just not something that can be fixed from JS.

You can make your code shorter but I don't think there will be any material performance improvements.

```
$('#details-speakers').click(function() {
    $('#home, #sessions-content, #cases-content').slideUp('slow');
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#speakers-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
        $('#details-speakers').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-sessions, #details-cases, #details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});

$('#details-sessions').click(function() {
    $('#home, #speakers-content, #cases-content').slideUp('slow');
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#sessions-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('#details-sessions').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-speakers, #details-cases, #details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});

$('#details-cases').click(function() {
    $('#home, #speakers-content, #sessions-content').slideUp('slow');
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#details").offset().top - 16}, 200, "swing");
  $('#cases-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('#details-cases').addClass('selected');
        //Remove other classes
        $('#details-speakers, #details-sessions, #details-workshops').removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Comment: You're still copy and pasting essentially the same code two times.

Comment: I only intended to answer the question about the smoothness, and if this question wasn't about performance I would've refactored the code as well. The other answers are definitely more elegant and better in general, but the long way is still marginally faster.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V programming leads straight to hell... I think you can do something like that:

```
var divs = $('#details-speakers, #details-sessions, #details-cases');

divs.click(function () {
    divs.not(this).add('#home').slideUp('slow');
    // animation with home and body
    $(this).slideDown('slow', function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        divs.not(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
}
```

And performance depends on a lot of thing (firebug is on, divs' content, divs' style, half-transparent backgrounds etc.) -- not just poor javascript.

Comment: I don't think this is correct/the same thing as the question.

Comment: Haven't tested your code, but it does look like you're missing a ");" at the very end.

Comment: It's also not $(this).slideDown(). You need to create 2 sets of selections, one for the content boxes and another for the links.

Comment: I like the use of divs.not(this)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a cleaner approach you're looking for how about something like this:

```
$(".my4Divs").click(function() {
    var self = this;
    $(".my4Divs").each(function() {
       if(self == this) {
          $(self).addClass("selected");
          ...
          ...
          return;
       }
       $(this).removeClass("selected");
       ...
       ...
    });
});
```